What's wrong with this "proof"? Induction Fibonacci Big-Oh
I can't find out what is wrong in this (computer science) induction exercise. Maybe I'm not cut out for this stuff.
Consider the following "proof" that the Fibonacci function, $F(n)$, defined as $F(1)=1$, $F(2)=2$, $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$, is $O(n)$:
Base case ($n \leq 2)$: $F(1)=1$, which is $O(1)$, and $F(2)=2$, which is $O(2)$.
Induction step ($n > 2$): Assume that the claim is true for $n'<n$. Consider $n$. $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$. By induction, $F(n-1)$ is $O(n-1)$ and $F(n-2)$ is $O(n-2)$. Then, $F(n)$ is $O((n-1)+(n-2))$ (by an identity presented earlier). Therefore $F(n)$ is $O(n)$, since $O((n-1)+(n-2))$ is $O(n)$.
Maybe it's the last part. $O((n-1)+(n-2))$ is $O(n)$. $O((n-1)+(n-2))$ does not equal $O(n)$ but of course $2n-3 \in O(n)$... and if we were to take $n=4$, we would have $O(3+2)=O(5)$, not $O(4)$...
I have some troubles with these "logic exercises"; I'm better at calculus... but perhaps I cracked it this time?

Do you know formal definition of big-O? For example, of course, $O(3+2)=O(5)=O(4)=O(1)$.

Yes have read the formal definition. Thanks... got a bit confused in this "fake proof", perhaps.

When we speak about $O(n)$, then, may be helpful, to think, that there is function $f(n)=n$ inside. For any fixed $c>0$ we have $c\cdot O(f)=O(c\cdot f)=O(f)$.

The error comes from the statement:
"Assume $F(n)=O(n)$ for $n < n'$."
This statement doesn't make sense. Saying $F(n)=O(n)$ is asymptotic notation, and defines behaviour of $F$ for all $n$ (larger than some $n''$). You cannot limit this behaviour to only a bounded set of $n$'ms beacuse that is not what big-$O$ means, and furthermore big-$O$ doesn't tell you anything about behaviour at a bounded space, but only about asymptotic behaviour.
A similar example would be "Assume $\lim_{n\to\infty}F(n) = c$ for $n\leq n'$."
In other words, as soon as you write $F(n)=O(n)$, you have defined the asymptotic behaviour of $F$. At that point your exercise would be finished, since $F(n)=O(n)$. The $n$ doesn't pay any role here, it's just notation. It would probably make things a lot clearer, if you instead wrote $F\in\{\text{Set of functions whose asymptotic behaviour at $\infty$ is linear}\}$. This is equivalent to $F(n)=O(n)$ or $F(n)\in O(n)$ (technically more correct).
Now it is more clear to see that
$F\in\{\text{Set of functions whose asymptotic behaviour at $\infty$ is linear}\} \text{ for all } n\leq n'$
doesn't make sense.
Notice that $F(n)=O(n)+O(n-1)=O(n)$ is completely correct, and there is no errors here. Indeed, if $F(n)=O(n)$ and $F(n)=F(n)+F(n-1)$ then $F(n)=O(n)$, which is fine.
If, instead you had $F(n)=G(n)+G(n-1)$, and you had a hypothesis $G(n)=O(n)$, THEN you could prove that $F(n)=O(n)$. Try to do it, and understand the difference.
My suggestion is to try to re-write the exercise using only epsilon-delta notation. Then you will get stuck and understand what the underlying problem is.
Nevertheless this is a very nice problem that I hadn't encountered before! It can be useful in teaching big-$O$ notation.

I know, that answer is wrote and accepted, but let me show you why math. induction cannot be applied in manner choose in OP. I tried to explain this many time to many mathematicians and, so, now I would like invite to judge math.stackexchange society.
I'll consider only positive functions.
When we wrote $g(n)=O(f(n)), n\to\infty$, then here $n$ is  so called bound, dummy, variable and actually it can be change to any other variable distinct from $f,g$. I.e. same as above is, for example, $g(m)=O(f(m)), m\to\infty$. It's better and possible not to write this variable if this does not cause ambiguity, for example, when we have functions from one variable we can write $g= O(f)$ or $g\in O(f)$.
So, when you would like to use big-O in math. induction, then you cannot appeal to an internal dummy variable $n$ of big-O  as a math. induction variable. Let me emphasize one more time: $O(f(n)), n\to\infty$ and $O(f(m)), m\to\infty$ are one and same set.
This is the same as, imagine, you would like to perform induction with respect to a variable $n $ in a formula $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m}f(n)$. You can carry out induction with respect to a variable $m$, it is free, but not with respect to a variable $n $, it is bound. $\sum$ is known as variable-binding operator (Dirk van Dalen, Logic and Structure, Springer, 2013, page 58)
Additionally let me show, that $O(n)=O(n+1)$, so, use left and right sides in math.induction as different cases have no sense. I'll consider it as $O(f)=O( g)$, where $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=n+1$.
Let take $\phi \in O(f)$, which gives, that $\exists C>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n>N, \phi(n)\leqslant C\cdot f(n)= C\cdot n < C\cdot (n+1)=C\cdot g(n)$, so $O(f)\subset O( g)$.
Now take $\phi \in O(g)$ which gives, that $\exists C>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n>N, \phi(n)\leqslant C\cdot g(n)= C\cdot (n+1)=C\cdot n +C\leqslant 2C \cdot n$, so $O(g)\subset O( f)$.
Last result easily can be extended to any increasing function i.e. for such functions $O(f(n))\subset O(f(n+1))$.

This is the actual correct answer +1.
Saying "$F(n')=O(n')$ for $n'\leq n$" doesn't make sense.  The sentence $F(n')=O(n')$ is an asymptotic notation, and is not something that can be satisfied for some bounded $n'$ values, but rather something that is satisfied for all (from a certain point onwards) $n'$ values. Re-writing this in the epsilon-delta notation, you (OP) will understand that the induction statement doesn't make sense, and that is where the error comes from.

Agree. Your example in comment shows one more attempt to use bound variable wrongly.

You can say things like $O(f(n)+f(n-1)+\ldots+f(n-k))=O(f(n))$ only if $k$ is constant and does not depend on $n$. However, if you would keep track of what happens in the 'proof', you end up adding exponentially many terms within the brackets. Yes, you are adding terms of $O(n)$, but always keep track of how many terms you are adding to draw any conclusions on the limiting behaviour of a function.

This is good. As I originally wrote, at $n=4$ it will not be $O(n)$...

This is incorrect.  OP assumes a statement for $n' < n$ and then proves another statement for $n$. There is no need for "opening the proof", and there is no exponential blowup in this procedure.
The error comes from the inductive hypothesis itself, which doesn't make sense as a statement. You cannot assume $F(n)=O(n)$ only for some bounded set of $n$'s, it's not how Big-O works.
